# How to set up React with Meteor?

Tags: meteor, reactjs

I have started learning meteor and decided to use it with react. Since one month, I had issues about which packages I should use.

At the end of the day , I know I should use webpack for codesplitting, react-router since it promises much more compatibility with other stuff related to react and lastly I don t want server-side-rendering since it lacks many of the things I want in my application( in short responsiveness of my app ).

Anyway, I checked lots of repos on github and read many articles etc. Since first day , I still hate meteor + react because it s been very confusing to decide between different combinations of using packages.

---

Finally my question is about which of the packages for data I should use with my pack. So my pack consists of

1. react
2. react-dom
3. react-router
4. webpack
5. babel

Which of the followings should I use to complete my pack.

1. react-meteor-data
2. react-mounter
3. anything else ?

I don t really know how meteor bootstraps, how it handles data, how it passes data to react, why are there weird mixins used within many projects on github etc. I am really exhausted. I should start my project and finish. Still trying to figure out how meteor works and choose between those packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're a beginner, I'd advise to use the following setup instead:

- [**React**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react). Install the npm package instead of what you find on Atmosphere, they're for an older version of Meteor, where npm support wasn't really a thing yet.
- [**Flow Router**](https://atmospherejs.com/kadira/flow-router) integrates really well with Meteor, it's really straightforward to use. Provides reactive variables and even server-side rendering, that will come in handy later when optimize your app for SEO.
- [**react-meteor-data**](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/react-meteor-data) is responsible for connecting Meteor and React. It provides the `createComponent` function that can turn Meteor subscriptions into React properties.
- [**react-mounter**](https://github.com/kadirahq/react-mounter) from npm. Use it when you define `Flow Router` routes to mount your React components to the DOM.

That's the basics you'll need to make an awesome webapp with Meteor and React. :)

At the beginning I'd **skip webpack**. It's awesome, but can easily make your learning curve a bit too steep. You'll know when to switch to it.

Comment: Hey man, I really appreciate your detailed answer and sincere approach. I wish I found your answer before. I don t even remember why I chose react-router over flow-router. Anyway your answer made many things clear for me.  Lastly I already know I definetely need #webpack# for code-splitting. My app is really big (around 15 pages ) and I don t want every user get those files which they don t need. So webpack is a must for me.  I have read about webpack code-splitting a lot. What would you recommend at this point ?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it, 15 pages is really a small webapp. You could spare a few kilobytes at the initial download, but you cause a **lot** more trouble than what you solve here. Meteor (in production mode) creates a single monolithic .js file for your entire webapp, so you won't have to worry about having to download dozens of files.

Comment: You should, but not at the beginning. :) Webpack enables a faster rebuild times for example, which is nice when your app grows. But it believe you'll find your actual app code to be a lot smaller than all the framework and package codes you'll need, and even that is dwarfed by all the content your users will have to download.

Comment: So I won t lose time to convert my app to use webpack right ? And my router choice is not effecting me about using webpack or not ?

Comment: Exactly. FlowRouter is independent of WebPack.