# What router and ui-framework to use in meteor?

Tags: meteor, rendering, url-routing

Just started to discover meteor. created app with DiscoverMeteor book, but misunderstood many moments. then read Your first meteor application and Your first meteor application books. Realized that Todos example is really too simple to cover many important things. And only after that I found the [official guide](http://guide.meteor.com/) on Meteor.com! now reading about all these complex (for my opinion) things. and have 2 questions:

1. What router should I prefer to use? I want to create fast app with lots of data loading from the server. Found information that Iron router is deprecated, and Flow router is recommended nowadays, but also found that flow router can not route on server, only on client. And that exactly client routing is the reason why for example soundcloud is really slow. So that is the question - I know nothing about server/client routing, but want to make right decision for the future project.
2. What ui-framework to use? I read that blaze is easy to start, but react js is really powerful. So: is Blaze enough for serious project (like a popular blog)? Or do I have to learn react js in order not to rewrite code in the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am working with Meteor 1.3.2.4, which is latest in market and believe, you don't have to do anything out of the box to go with experimental UI-Frameworks and stuff.

1. Blaze template which is handlebars based implementation is best.
2. Blaze template is very well glued with **Socket.io**, **futures** and **DDP** implementation for cutting edge implementation for asynchronous and reactive behaviour on UI.
3. Blaze is really good for cumbersome, heavy data websites as well. If you have any doubt, i can skype and show you what i have implemented in just 2 days on development using everything given by Meteor.
4. **React.js, Koa.js** (re-written Express framework), **express** etc are very good and powerful, but I think implementing it at initial level of your grasp is overkill. Go with Blaze first.
5. There are hundered sitting and developing Meteor.js just for you to be comfortable. I am not at all biased, I am giving you my open opinion.
6. I worked with **Laravel 5.2, Play framework, MEAN.io, DJango** in past, but believe there is nothing like pure Meteor js with there own packages. There are many videos on youtube like Meteor nights and stuff where you can find the developers from all around the world developing huge stuff just using stuff given by Meteor js.
7. For routing **flow-router** is good, even **iron:router** is awesome and easily gettable.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-QtrkXKvQFc) can guide you very well.

Comment: thank you for answer! I got it about Blaze and that both iron and flow router are good instruments. but i really feel worry about rendering and routing on the client side. can it be the problem if i have really data-heavy app? for example, blog. apps like todos and other examples are too simple and not connected with real life, i think..

Comment: what  i have found in official meteor guide:


Render performance varies a lot depending on the situation. All three libraries are very quick at rendering simple apps, but can take a noticeable amount of time with more complex apps.
Angular and React have had more performance optimization work put into them than Blaze and in general will perform better. However, there are some cases when Blaze does better (for instance an {{#each}} over a changing cursor).
One test benchmarks Angular 2 as the best, followed by React and Angular 1, followed by Blaze.

what can you say about this moment?

Comment: I cannot comment over this write away as Angular 2 has recently been with people. But I would tell you that Angular js's learning curve is exponential. I am working on very heavy duty app that contains more than 1 million records and my stuff goes smooth with iron and blaze. You are eager to hunt angular 2, definitely go for it but techincally don't overkill your applications unnecessary with something whose cheap and efficient substitute was already with Meteor.

Comment: i got it! thank you! actually I realized that i need server side rendering, because ssr is a solution for 1) seo problems of meteor and 2) slow initial loading. BUT. i can not find any information how to properly do ssr with blaze and iron/flow. on the other side there are good solutions for ssr with react and flow. so that is my choice. thank you for the conversation again!

Answer (score 0):

Flow Router is the recommended router by the official [Meteor Guide](http://guide.meteor.com/routing.html). It's also the popular choice these days, and for a reason: it's a high quality router implementation.

As for MVC, it's really like choosing a religion. React has a huge community, possibly a bright future, and it's not Meteor-only unlike Blaze. But some folks find Blaze templates nicer than JSX files. I think it's easier to get help on StackOverflow if you pick React, but Blaze might be easier to get started.

Maybe this post helps a bit: [How to set up React with Meteor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36890816/how-to-set-up-react-with-meteor/36892224#36892224)